# One fontawesome icon is rendering while the other isn't?

Tags: css, font-awesome

This is probably a rookie question but I'm stuck with this and have gone through the troubleshooting steps [here](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Troubleshooting#some-icons-dont-show-up).

I am using a local copy of `fontawesome-all.min.css` in my assets which I have imported in `main.css` as follows:

```
@import url(fontawesome-all.min.css);
```

The `fontawesome-all.min.css` has the fonts I am looking for `fa-envelope` and `fa-graduation-cap`. However, when I use them on my webpage, `fa-envelope` renders but `fa-graduation-cap` doesn't. Where am I going wrong?

```
<li><a href="#" class="fa-envelope"><span class="label">Email</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="fa-graduation-cap"><span class="label">Google Scholar</span></a></li>
```

Comment: I had similar issue in the past. please mention your font-awesome version and check if this tag is available in your version. In new version some icons are coming with fab- mix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add the class on the `a` tag. Add font-awesome classes inside a `<i>` tag, like given below:

```
<li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> <span class="label">Email</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i><span class="label">Google Scholar</span></a></li>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/NWROWmZ

---

If you don't have the latest version you can either download this file or use directly also inside the `link` tag: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css

---

To get the latest versions classes, visit the official documentation here and just search the icon there and click on it to find all details about it: https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery

Comment: Thanks a ton! Can you also help me understand why it didn't work in the <a> tag but did in the <i> tag?

Comment: @VishakhaLall Before HTML5 (current version: html5). There were two tag 1.`<b>Some Text</b>` and 2.`<i>Some Text</i>`, these tags were used to make text **Bold** and _Italics_ respectively.

Comment: In HTML 5 two new tags were introduced `<strong>Some Text</strong>` and 2.`<em>Some Text</em>`, Where strong stands for **bold** and em stands for _Emphasized or Italics_.

Comment: This thus not mean that `<b>` and `<i>` tag will
not work from now, but `strong` and `em` are
considers as best practice.

Comment: So Font Awesome recommends using `<i>` tag as `i`
reference to icon. But it is totally fine to use
any tag like you were using the `a` tag.

Comment: Example: It is a rule in python that the code
should be in proper indentation but it is a best
practice that `Constants` should be all caps.

Answer (score 0):

fa and fas is missing

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="fa fa-envelope"><span class="label">Email</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="fas fa-graduation-cap"><span class="label">Google Scholar</span></a></li>
</ul>
```